# how to edit Xcode >> Main >> iOS navigation title for a Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I edit, or remove, the navigation title "Session info and parameters:" ?

I can't find any Xcode command that accesses this title

[image]

Comment: Did you look in the code you added to `first_ViewController.swift`?

Comment: Yes, it is not there.  However, that is how it was initially set.  But I removed that code.  I've also done realclean and restarted Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the label for "Session info and parameters:" defined within Main.storyboard and deleted it.